# Android - Multiple queries for recyclerview (Firebase)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working with recylerviews and Firebase. I am using FirebaseUI to populate data to my recyclerview. I was wondering if it was possible to use two queries within my fragment. The query that should be executed should be dependent of if a node in the database exists.

Database Structure:

[image]

If the **address** child is present in the **users** node, my fragment should query the users node. If not it should query the routes node. Is this possible?

Basically here I am making by query which gets me all markers:

```
Query keyQuery = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(sharedPreferences.getString("school", null)).child("markers");
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.markerRecyclerview);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<FirebaseMarker> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<FirebaseMarker>()
            .setQuery(keyQuery, FirebaseMarker.class)
            .build();
```

Inside my onBindViewHolder method I have an onClick on each item in the recyclerview. When the item is clicked, the user goes to a new activity. In this new activity the user can press a button which will add the address node under the users/userId node. What pressing that button means is that the user have chosen that marker. So I only want to show that marker information in the recyclerview and not every marker in the database.

```
 holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),MainActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("databaseKey", key);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```

I was thinking that: If a **address** and **time** node was inserted in the users node, I could just query this, which would make it easier.

Comment: So, you want to attach a different query to the `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` depending on whether `address` is present under the current user's node? Can you provide some example code of where this would occur? You should just be able to initialise the adapter with a different `FirebaseRecyclerOptions` instance.

Comment: I have updated my post. Does it make sense?

Comment: Do you think it is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible, although I think you'd first need to check whether the user has selected a marker and then decide which query to attach to the `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`.

To do that, it would likely be necessary to add a list of users that have selected each marker under the marker nodes, something like:

```
users
  userId
    selectedMarker      // the ID of the marker selected by this user
    ...
markers
  markerId
    ...
    selectedUsers       // list of user IDs that have selected this marker
```

Then, if the `users` node contains a `selectedMarker` value, you could use the below query to get all markers selected by this specific user:

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
        .child(schoolId).child("markers")
        .orderByChild("selectedUsers/"+userId).equalTo(true);
```

Where `schoolId` is from your `sharedPreferences.getString("school", null)` and `userId` is the currently logged in user's unique ID.

To check if the user has selected a marker, could be as simple as:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
        .child(schoolId).child("users").child(userId)
        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.child("selectedMarker").exists()) {
                    // Attach above query to FirebaseRecyclerAdapter
                } else {
                    // Attach markers reference (no query) to FirebaseRecyclerAdapter
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        });
```

However, if you just want to display the user's single selected marker, it's likely that you don't need to use the `RecyclerView` at all, and could just use a separate view to display details about the user's selected marker.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems that your last point is correct, regarding that I only need to display the user's single selected marker. I want to use `recylerview` to show all markers, and just a seperate textview if the `address` node exists under the user node

Comment: The problem I have is that, when the databaseReference is ran within in the `if-else` statement, it is not executing properly.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Ks0c0LJT. This is how I do it. Am I making any mistakes. My screen just shows one populated row with no data.

Comment: That looks OK, but you'll need to remember that `onDataChange()` is asynchronous, so you'll need to call the `FirebaseRecyclerOptions` setup code inside this block if you aren't already.

Comment: Inside the `else statement`? It is all done in the same method

Comment: Yes, inside the `else` statement within the `onDataChange()` block, because this will return in the background after retrieving data from the database, so you need to ensure `markersDatabase` has a value when creating `FirebaseRecyclerOptions`.

Comment: I have done this: https://pastebin.com/dUzpJQKY. This returns this error: 'NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.firebase.ui.database.ObservableSnapshotArray com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions.getSnapshots()' on a null object reference' Is that because the `markersDatabase ` is null? If it is that is confusing as the `markers` node is not empty

Comment: Its likely because the `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` is being initialised with a `FirebaseRecyclerOptions` that is `null` because it hasn't reached the `onDataChange()` block yet, so you'll need to move that into there too.

Comment: I have done this. https://pastebin.com/RHrESEA5. But I need to use the FirebaseRecyclerOptions instance later in my code. Is ther another way?

Comment: You just need to move your `adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter[...]` logic to the same place where you create your `options` variable (inside `onDataChange`). It might be easier if you move all the `RecyclerView` setup code into a method and then call that method inside `onDataChange`. This way your `RecyclerView` is only setup once you know which query and options you need to use.

Comment: Yes, I have done what you suggested: https://pastebin.com/A6zximLV. This returns me an error saying: NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening()' on a null object reference. The adapter should not be null, as there is data in database

Comment: If you have `adapter.startListening()` in your `onStart()` method (and `stopListening()` in `onStop()`), you may need to check that `adapter` is not `null` before calling them (`if (adapter != null) adapter.startListening()`), and then also call `adapter.startListening()` inside your `recylerViewSetup()` method once it's all setup.

Comment: @Grimthorr please help me with this problem here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55259345/combining-two-arrays-of-model-class-type-firebase-android